# rsync ionice softraid - limit io locally?

Tags: rsync, software-raid, ionice

I know this seems to be a recurrent question but it's been troubling for a while now, so if anyone has a brilliant idea please let me know.

---

### **My Setup**

---

**OS**

- Debian Wheezy

**HDDs**

- 2 x 240GB SSD for system *(sda & sdb in RAID1 - md0=/boot md1=/
  md2=/tmp md3=swap)*
- 2 x 2TB SATA for storage *(sdc & sdd in RAID1 - md4=/home)*

**Scheduler Settings**

- [cfq] for drives sda sdb sdc sdd *(from my understanding ionice only
  works with cfq)*
- cat /sys/block/md*/queue/scheduler returns `none` as the only option
  for all arrays

**Remote Storage**

- Simple remote storage space with no rsync server/deamon running on it
  *(hence not using --rsync-path)*

---

### **What I'm doing**

---

- I am providing a backup service to a few users using a simple script
  (triggered by cron).
- The remote storage is automounted using automount & sshfs when the
  script runs.
- The rsync cmd I use is
  `nice -n 19 ionice -c2 -n7 rsync -rtvuczhq --delete --log-file=$LOG $SRC $DEST`

---

### **The issue**

---

> While this works, there is a significant impact on the IO (cpu is fine) and simple music streams originating from the server are delayed/lagged along with any cmds requiring disk access.

---

### **The questions**

---

> Is there something obviously wrong in the rsync cmd I am using?
>   Is there anything I can do to reduce rsync's IO usage or prioritise other processes over it?

Merry Xmas, Happy New Year and Many thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you tried to throttle rsync with `--bwlimit`? Also, I usually omit the -v (verbose) flag when running from crons.

Comment: @Gmck - doesn't `--bwlimit` apply to network bandwidth? (which really isn't an issue). I will see if the -v has an impact (am using it for logs).

Comment: My question needs a little more explanation. Instead of sshfs, can you try with ssh and --bwlimit?

Comment: @Gmck - I will try and report back (tomorrow) but my guts tell me that it got something to do with the `-c` (checksums) option. Would you know if there is a particular reason for rsync to be immune to the ionice params I'm passing?

Comment: Fore sure checksums will add to I/O, but I am not sure it would cause that great of a bottleneck. Try without and see. I just tried with checksum from one of my data centers to a remote backup with 100mb links. It's a little slower, but not agonizing.

Comment: @Gmck - Well I knew there was a reason I was doing it via sshfs (the reason being that my provider for the remote storage does not provide a real shell hence no direct ssh connection). The only other mean of accessing is sftp which rsync doesn't support.. Any hints?

Comment: My guess is mounting via sshfs, which is fuse, is a contributor to the problem. There could be other factors on the provider's ends as well, but that's pretty hard to speculate. I have used lftp - which has a mirroring support and will transfer across sftp, bypassing fuse alltogether. `lftp -e "mirror -eRv /local/dir/ /remote/dir; quit;" sftp://user@server:port`